# Try to solve the following differential equation: $2y''=e^y$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve this equation:
$$2y''=e^y$$
No $x$ in equation so: 
$$y''=P'P , y'=p
\\
\implies 2P'P=e^y$$ 
After the integrating on both sides I got:
$$P^2=e^y$$
and back to $y$:
$$y'2=e^y
\\
\implies y'=\sqrt[]{e^y}$$
and now how I solve the integral? I hope I didn't mistake in my way
thanks.

Comment: What does y' mean? dy/what?

Comment: You write $y'=p$, then you need to write an equation for $dp/dy$ in terms of $p$ and $y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is just how to solve $y' = \sqrt{e^y}$, notice that $\sqrt{e^y} = (e^y)^{\frac12} = e^{\frac y2}$ so your differential equation is
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = e^{\frac y2}$$
and this is a separable equation:
$$e^{-\frac y2}dy = dx$$

Comment: yeah, that's what I did but the answer is: $$y=-2ln(1-(x/2))$$ and I didn't understand why

Comment: When you integrate the separated equation you get $-2e^{-\frac y2} = x + c$.  Let's take $c = -2$.  Then $e^{-\frac y2} = 1 - \frac x2$, hence $-\frac y2 = \ln(1 - \frac x2)$, hence $y = -2\ln(1 - \frac x2)$.

Comment: Of course, you shouldn't just arbitrarily choose what $c$ is.  I did that to get my answer to look like yours.  Presumably, since there are no $c$'s in your answer, there must some initial conditions or something like that.  You should solve the equation with the arbitrary constants in place and then use those initial conditions to determine what they should be.

Answer (score 2):

From $2 p p' = e^y$ you should get $p^2 = e^y + c$ or $y' = \pm \sqrt{e^y + c}$.
Then use $$ \int \dfrac{dy}{\sqrt{\exp(y)+c}} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{c}} \ln \left( \dfrac{\sqrt{c}-\sqrt{\exp(y)+c}}{\sqrt{c} + \sqrt{\exp(y)+c}}\right) + c_1$$
On the other hand, for the special case $c=0$,
$$\int \dfrac{dy}{\sqrt{\exp(y)}} = \int \exp(-y/2)\; dy = - 2 \exp(-y/2) + c_1$$